# [Pure CSS Auto Carousel]: Need to add dots in pure css auto-carousel

Tags: html, css, sass, slider, carousel

I have tried to built a Auto-carousel which is pure css based solution. But i am facing issue in adding "dots" to my carousel in a css driven approach.

functionality required:

- swipe/slide
- auto-play (infinite)
- dots indicator
- css3 animation

If anyone from the community can help me in this project would be very helpful.

Comment: JSBin Code snippet: https://jsbin.com/hopajacavi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: do you want it dynamically?

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu yes length of carousel can change.

Comment: do you want that dots to be clickable or just viewable

Comment: just viewable @Neptotech-vishnu

Comment: but **dynamic means there will be javascript** is it ok?

Comment: can you provide me soln. for fixed image length ? @Neptotech-vishnu Because i have to avoid JS .

Comment: posted the answer please check-P.S: spent 2 days to find a way

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer,

```css
:root{
  --numeberOfImages:4;
  --Seconds: 8s;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: coral;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 10px 25px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  55% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
}
@keyframes mmo {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-1.75rem);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(1.75rem * (var(--numeberOfImages) - 1)));
  }
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  animation: slide var(--Seconds) infinite; 
}

ol,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.backbt {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #333;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}
.listbt {
  display: inline-block;
}
.caslnav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
/*------------------*/
.curtbt {
  display: inline-block;
  /*
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  margin: 0.125rem;
  */

  /*uncommment and use the above for diffrent style*/

  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0rem;

  background-color: white;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;

  animation: mmo var(--Seconds) steps(var(--numeberOfImages), start) infinite; 
}
.emptbt {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" /><!-- photo -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" /><!-- photo -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" /><!-- photo -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400" /><!-- photo -->
      </div>
      <aside class="caslnav">
        <ol>
          <li class="listbt"><div class="backbt">O</div></li><!-- grey background -->
          <li class="listbt"><div class="backbt">O</div></li><!-- grey background -->
          <li class="listbt"><div class="backbt">O</div></li><!-- grey background -->
          <li class="listbt"><div class="backbt">O</div></li><!-- grey background -->
        </ol>
      </aside>
      <aside class="caslnav">
        <ol>
          <li class="listbt"><div class="curtbt">o</div></li><!--white button-->
          <li class="listbt"><div class="emptbt"></div></li><!-- spacer -->
          <li class="listbt"><div class="emptbt"></div></li><!-- spacer -->
          <li class="listbt"><div class="emptbt"></div></li><!-- spacer -->
        </ol>
      </aside>
    </div>
```

## Features

- ***3/4 Dynamic- means you have to only change `numbers` in css `variable`*** ,and **NO need to copy past code** *or so*
- use of css variables
- Answers your question
- With two style of buttons (see the commented lines)
- Only css

**Note:** *change HTML accordingly for number of images*

Comment: Thanks for your effort ! But if we need to accomodate "scroll/swipe" functionality in the same what changes need to make to utilise he same codebase.

Comment: Thats not a part of this question & again I can answer that only if you provide the code in which scroll or swipe doesn't work,sorry please

Comment: You can utilise the same code which you have provided for scroll functionality (using JS). becoz. my code is in react. @neptotech

Comment: Works well when all images are the same size... Otherwise the animation splits images of different widths into the same slide.

Comment: Code snippet doesn't work in firefox. Only works with 4 images in chrome. Changing the variable and number of images to anything but 4 doesn't work...

Comment: keyframes not work if more than 4 images, it's breaking!